# Don't forget about the chat?

Tags: discussion

During these first few days of the site formation, using the chatroom can be a great resource (since as right now, the site has only been up for a few hours, and some of these discussions may be easier in real-time to narrow down)

> http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing

Feel free to visit and ask simple questions or get clarification on things that have been asked. I'll be lurking in there, and I'm sure people will find resource in there. Come on in!

Comment: Don't forget about the chat is not a question.  Also, 1090 chat rooms now?  Wow!

Comment: lol, and I know!

Comment: @Peter.K, Any chance you unfroze the room?

Answer (score 2):

Can mods resurrect chat rooms?  [The official one](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing) has died and been buried.

> This room has been automatically frozen for inactivity
>
> The last message was posted 24 days ago.

Comment: *ahem* Try again :D