# On non-mandatory regular DSP Chat Meetups

Tags: discussion, moderation, chat

[Don't [we]  forget about the chat?](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/dont-forget-about-the-chat) The question was asked 5.5 years ago, and [answered](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1232/15892) (only) two years later (3.5 years ago) by [endolith](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/endolith).

Since I was not busy enough eating and drinking during some end-of-2016 celebrations, I ended up on our [Signal Processing chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1090/signal-processing). It was relatively calm. It still is.

To promote an interaction between SE.DSP users, I do propose that some non-mandatory regular DSP Chat Meetups could be installed. The main idea is to remain non-mandatory, yet regular (albeit not-uniform), without having to plan meetings, but allowing some of us to chat, as they like, if they drop by. To discuss about policies, feedback on questions (to close, etc.), tags, whatever...

Several proposals follow (non-exclusive):

- Nyquist-shaped, every XXX day, to allow perfect sampling: might require a calendar with day indices
- week-shaped, every [XXXday] (Monday, Tuesday...): might not be convenient for people with an agenda (for instance not possible on [Friday, I'm in Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_QC00oZ1q10))
- month-shaped, every XXX^th day, the first, tenth, etc.: detrimental to February, but a little jitter can be beneficial
- DSP-shaped (my favorite), **every D.S.P. day (4th, 16th, 19th)**: D is the fourth letter, S, the 19th, P the 16th.  In a word, jitter plus irregular sampling. Two of them are powers of 2 (4 and 16), 19 is the 8th prime (and aside the maximum number of 4th powers needed to sum to any number), they are different modulo seven (4, 2 and 5). Not a [Golomb ruler](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GolombRuler.html) nor a [Costas array](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CostasArray.html), but 4, 16, 19 are easy to remember. And three times a month (on the average) is base-10 compatible.

One of the main blind spots is the time zone, but let us allow some day-to-day folding. Aside, 19 is not a [Hamming number](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers). And there are NO Fibonacci, Bell nor Catalan numbers.

Comment: Even though you haven't received any answers or comments so far, at least this question of yours motivated me to show my bearded face in our chat room. And, you wouldn't believe it, I even met one other lone DSPer!!! (OK, that was a one-off ...)

Comment: It'll happen some other time ... I'll try to be there more often (you could call it a New Year's resolution :)